# Ni-MH battery charging issue - custom built transformers, LM317 gets warm

Tags: charging, lm317

I had one variable voltage power supply built and I have been using it frequently.

Although I had no issue until charging Ni-MH and Ni-Cad batteries with this power supply. Lead acid battery, lithium-ion charging working pretty well. But it seems like Ni-MH and Ni-Cad charges gets too hot for linear regulator LM317. I'm currently charging each cell with about 5 volts and it consumes way too much current compared to other batteries. What can I do now?

Comment: Ni-MH (note capitals for chemical elements) cells require constant current charging, not constant voltage.

Comment: Could you elaborate ? lm317 provides constant currrent as well, it is about 110 milliamp (checked). I'm new in this charging stuff so I will need some more info to get what is going on here.

Comment: https://batteryuniversity.com/.

Comment: Sealed NiMH and NiCd batteries are tricky to charge, but I think it is not the battery chemistry that fails your approach, but the power calculation for LM317 element. Can you, please, show the schematics of your setup?

Comment: @Transistor: I would have referred him to the same site, but it seems they are missing the key currents and voltages or they are lost in the tons of text, which makes it hard for a seasoned technician/engineer to dig through, and a lot harder for a novice. Their business is making and selling battery chargers and analyzers (Cadex Electronics) so it makes sense that they will not give out all the details about charging batteries.

Comment: @EdinFifić Some people conclude that providing near maximal; info is the way to get customers. HP used to provide full diagrams and in depth descriptions of the functionality of their products. Battery university does not hold too too much back.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Your description is slightly unclear, but I think you're saying that your LM317 regulator gets too hot when charging Ni-Cd and Ni-MH cells compared to chargin Li-Ion cells, and that you are using 5V as an input to LM317. Correct?
 The heat comes from the larger difference between the 5V input and the average 1.2V of the cells, compared to average 3.8V for Li-Ion.
You have 3.8V vs. 1.2V, which is 3 times the difference in voltage, and therefore 3 times the heat at the same current.

Below is the answer I wrote earlier, before I have re-read your question (or you may have edited it):
 You need to limit both the maximum voltage **and** the current.
The Ni-MH cells have higher capacity so they will draw a charging current for a longer time, but they also have higher internal resistance which causes them to heat up more than Ni-Cd. You have not specified the sizes nor the capacities of the cells in your question.
 The charging voltage of the Ni-MH cells should never go above 1.6V.
The maximum charging current is 1C, C being the capacity of the cell, so if the cell has a capacity of 2000mAh (2Ah), the maximum charging current should be 2A.
**However**, it is better to charge it at a lower current, usually no more than 0.3C to 0.5C. Many chargers use the 0.1C (0.2A for a 2000mAh cell).
Once the cell is charged up, it can have a small "trickle charge" current flowing into it without damaging it, and it value is no more than 0.02C or 1/20 of the capacity (0.04A or 40mA for a 2000mAh cell).
To make it simple and safe, you could set your voltage regulator to 1.6V (or 1.55V) and place a 1-3.3Ω, 1W resistor at its output to limit the current. It could take anywhere from 5 to 20 hours to charge it fully, depending on its charge level at the beginning).
Otherwise, you could use a CC/CV DC-DC converter, set its current to 0.3C and its voltage to 1.55V. It would be faster and more efficient.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. The difference is huge and that's why it's heating up. I have ready everything you wrote. I'll then use a 3.3ohm resistor and set it's voltage to 1.6V. Hopefully it will reduce the heat in both transformers and LM317. Thank you.

Comment: I can't show the schematic now. I had built this by seeing one of the video from youtube xD

Comment: Because the heat is also the issue here, you either need a lower input voltage to the LM317 (a transformer with a lower output voltage, like 2-3Vac) or a CC/CV DC-DC converter (much more efficient, no heat).

Comment: Modern NimH - typically over about 1800 mAh cannot support ANY long term trickle charge without damage. Older lower capacity cells had recombination chemicals to allow H2 + O2 to recombine. Moden cells bent the electrolyte and dry out and die. [I've used over 500,000 NiMH AA cells in products along the way].

Comment: Then the Battery University was slightly wrong, as they said that a trickle charge is still doable, but no more than half that of the Ni-Cd, namely 0.05C for Ni-MH.